# MySQL - How to find through query if a string contains substring in Column

Tags: mysql, laravel, string

I am a beginner with MySQL and trying to write a query to find if a string contains a substring in Column through if statement,

Let's say for example I have a column in a table with String values

> This is an example of String

Through the query will try to check if "**This is an example of String**" contains **This is** in then it may return either `yes/1` or `no/0` for not containing ***this is***

- I gave it try with the following query :

  *SELECT POSITION("this is" IN column1) AS result
  FROM table;*

But I couldn't have an idea how should I write with if statement in MySQL query

Could anyone help me with this? please let me know if this is the correct way and possible through MySQL query?

Comment: See REPLACE() and CHAR_LENGTH, or regular expressions

Comment: POSITION() is essentially a pointer to LOCATE(), so you can see the details about using LOCATE() here (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate), ie. its return values if the string is not found, or a parameter is Null.  Either CASE or IF() would solve your need to return either a 1 or 0, depending on whether the string is found or not (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html)

Comment: @Strawberry - seems you didn't understand the question :)
I don't want to replace the substring, want to find either of boolean value through if statement

Comment: @Craig - Thank you for the replay, Isn't the POSITION() and LOCATE() MySQL function works same ?

Comment: @Craig - please correct me if I get the wrong scenario between them since I'm beginner, guidance may help me to clear the confusion

Comment: @user212010909097 If you use LOCATE instead of POSITION then the only difference is that the query become 2 symbols shorter. No another difference.

Comment: It seems you didn't understand my suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is correct except the comma instead of `IN` keyword must be used.

```
SELECT POSITION('this is', column1) AS result FROM table;
```

Also you may use not `POSITION` but `LOCATE` function (they are aliases as mentioned in comments)

```
SELECT LOCATE('this is', column1) AS result FROM table;
```

or INSTR() function (in this case you must sswap operands)

```
SELECT INSTR(column1, 'this is') AS result FROM table;
```

All queries returns positive integer if the substring is found, zero `0` if the substring is not found, and NULL if any operand is NULL.

If you want to return `1/0` output only then you must check what one of these variants is obtained, and convert to needed value. For example,

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LOCATE('this is', column1)
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END AS result FROM table;
```

`LOCATE('this is', column1)` is treated as TRUE returning 1 when the substring is found, and FALSE returning 0 otherwise.

---

Pay attention - if you use case-sensitive collation then `'this is'` substring will **not** be found in `'This is an example of String'` value!

If you need to apply case-insensitive search then you may specify case-insensitive collation explicitly, or apply a function which converts all symbols to lower or upper case (of course, literals does not need in this, they can be printed in needed case). For example,

```
SELECT LOCATE('this is', LOWER(column1)) AS result FROM table;
```

Comment: Thank you :> what an explanation! it clear all my doubts.